# Cannot fatload Kernel image files in U-Boot?

Tags: pi-2, u-boot

Good day folks,

I am here with a problem that has so far stumped me completely.

When I use U-Boot to load files into memory from my SD Card, it works completely fine when I fatload my device tree files.

However, when I attempt to fatload the kernel into memory with the command

```
fatload mmc 0:1 ${loadaddr} kernel7.img
```

U-Boot returns the following error:

```
reading kernel7.img
** Unable to read file kernel7.img **
```

I do not believe U-Boot keeps a log of what it performs, but if it does, could someone point the location out to me so I can append it to this question?

I am at a real loss to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Not a U-boot expert, but for me it seems the file is not where you expect it to be. You can check what files exist with:

```
ls mmc 0
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/52829)

Comment: @Bex tried to write it another way